# Is it possible to use belongs_to when the id field is defined using store_accessor?

Tags: database, activerecord, belongs-to

Is it possible to do something like the following?

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
    store_accessor :registration, :manufacturer_id
    belongs_to :manufacturer
end
```

I tried this but get

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError:
  can't write unknown attribute `manufacturer_id`
```